# executing a Linux command from PDF file in a PDF viewer

Tags: pdf, latex

Is it possible to execute a Linux command from a PDF file shown in a PDF viewer?

More specific: I generate PDF files from LaTeX using `pdflatex`. What I would like to do is to include some symbol or text in the PDF file which starts a Linux command when the user clicks on it. Typically I'm using `evince` to show PDF files.

I'm not sure whether it is at all possible to execute commands from PDF files in a viewer, and if it is possible, which packages and LaTeX commands would be required to include the symbol or text and the associated command in the PDF file?

(Alternatively, is there at least a way to obtain the number of the current page shown in the PDF viewer? That would help to some extent.)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This sounds like an xy problem. What do you want to do with the current page number?

Comment: (also be aware that different pdf viewers use different page numbers. Some follow the numbers in the pdf, e.g. will show roman numbers for the front matter, others will just count from 1 to n)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately and rather fortunately you cant do that.The pdf standard doesnt allow to run shell scripts. That would be a HUGE security oversight.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37737/36296